# Rebuilding RAID 10 after crash

Tags: raid

I am running a RAID 10

The structure

1x USB drive contains the systems and is the bootup disk.
4x 2T drives contain the RAD10 Array.

What happened:

•   3x 2T disks and 1 x 1.5T disk
•   Recently the 1.5T disk failed. 
•   I replaced the disk with a 2T (now there are 4 x 2T disks).
•   The RAID10 rebuilt as it was supposed to. 
•   All my files were there and all was restored.

The problem

•   The size of the RAID should have increased because of the new 2T disk. Instead it reported more or less the same as the old set of disks.
•   I deleted the new disk and tried again. 
•   Now I have lost some files:
o   User 1 has all her files. 
o   User 2 has all her files.
o   Steve (user3) has no files. The media/user3 directory is empty.
o   Steve (User 3) cannot login. 
o   At boot up the system says "The disk drive for /Steve/media is not ready yet or not present" and I have to Skip.

> cat /proc/mdstat

Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md126 : inactive sdc12
      1935228928 blocks super 1.2

md127 : inactive sda10 sdb11
      3870457856 blocks super 1.2

unused devices:

> mdadm --examine –scan

ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=84bf1f46:5cef1a6f:9189cfec:cba29486 name=RAIDServer:0
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=116c8018:dee8bccb:c746ed3e:b6848e87 name=RAIDServer:0
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=1be91f0a:c6a9b3c1:e9496603:a6b8f6ed name=RAIDServer:0

> ls -l /media

total 28
drwxrwx---  19 ali   ali  4096 Sep 24 21:03 AliServer
drwxrwx---  16 viv   viv  4096 Sep 24 14:21 VivServer
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root  root    7 Jun 14 17:22 floppy -> floppy0
drwxrwxr-x   2 root  root 4096 Jun 14 17:22 floppy0
drwxrwxr-x   2 root  root 4096 Jul 20 17:14 home
drwxr--r--   4 steve home 4096 Jul 20 17:14 house
drwxr-x---+  5 root  root 4096 Jun 17 23:14 steve
drwxr-x---+  2 root  root 4096 Sep 24 13:52 viv

> sudo smartctl -i /dev/sda

smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.16.0-43-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST2000DX001-1CM164
Serial Number:    Z1E9A0MZ
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 07aea6f07
Firmware Version: CC43
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Sep 25 12:58:32 2015 SAST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

> sudo smartctl -i /dev/sdb

smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.16.0-43-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST2000DX001-1CM164
Serial Number:    Z1E96B7V
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 07aa87f87
Firmware Version: CC43
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Sep 25 12:58:54 2015 SAST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST2000DX001-1CM164
Serial Number:    Z1E96B7B
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 07aa6f27b
Firmware Version: CC43
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Sep 25 12:59:18 2015 SAST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

> sudo smartctl -i /dev/sdd

smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.16.0-43-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST2000DX001-1CM164
Serial Number:    Z1E8T1HC
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0796a10ae
Firmware Version: CC43
User Capacity:    2,000,398,934,016 bytes [2.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Sep 25 12:59:36 2015 SAST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

BOOT up drive is usb

> sudo smartctl -i /dev/sde

smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.16.0-43-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Caviar SE Serial ATA
Device Model:     WDC WD800JD-00JNA0
Serial Number:    WD-WMAM94564663
Firmware Version: 05.01C05
User Capacity:    80,026,361,856 bytes [80.0 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA/ATAPI-6 (minor revision not indicated)
Local Time is:    Sat Sep 26 10:50:55 2015 SAST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

MUST STRESS THIS

The administrator cannot get access to any files. Media/steve is empty . home/steve has files on the boot up disk but not on the RAID disks.

User1 and User 2 with limited access to their files both have all their files intact on the RAID10 Array.

Evidently all the files are in the RAID but steve (super user and admin) cannot accessible his files. Nor can root or admin.

In the past I have simply rebuilt the RAID and it has restored the files. Now it says the Raid is not active. I fear I have already tried too hard to fix that.

The drive array has 2.5T of files stored on it. It took 3 days to back up before it went down. It will be a mission to restore. I hope that there is something I can do to avoid that.

Please help. Let me know what other reports to give you.

Regards
Steve.